# Why is the electrical type text of a pin always shown in KiCad V5?

Tags: kicad

I'm taking my very first steps with KiCad and found that when I am editing a new component the text of the electrical type assigned to the pin is always visible.

Is there any way to remove it?

Comment: During editing you might want to change that text so why remove it?

Comment: Did you try placing your component in a schematic?  The types do not appear on the schematic.  And the answer to your question, is no.  In the Symbol Editor, you cannot turn off type of pin.

Comment: thank you guys for your answer. i found the way there's a button on left side of the screen it's to show or hide the electrical type...

Answer (score 3):

The button with the question mark on the left sidebar disables/enables the electrical type. in V5
[image: Example image]